# Jquery Datepicker - How to get array of date from select option in another function, and pass it to disabledate in datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datepicker

i have a problem with datepicker. First of all, i'm using [gijgo datepicker](https://gijgo.com/datepicker/configuration/disableDates) and codeigniter. My client want to see disable date based on user selected area (villa, camping ground, homestay, etc). Each area has spesific data (booking date), so if another person want to booking that area in the same day, that date or day cannot be choosen.

*First step: user select the area that he/ she wants using combo box.

Second step: user select the date (datepicker will show disable date)*

Combo box process:

```
$("#area").change(function(){
     var disdate = [];
     var area= $(this).val();
     $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('reservation/getDate');?>",
        method: "POST",
        data: {area: area},
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
           var i;
           for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
              disdate.push(data[i]['startdate']); // startdate is booking date in database
           }
        }
     });
     return disdate;
     loadDatePicker(disdate);
  });
```

Datepicker process:

```
$(function loadDatePicker(disdate) {
     var disdatepick = disdate;
     var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate());
     $('#startDate').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'materialdesign',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        allowInputToggle: true,
        disableDates: disdatepick, //put disable date array here
        minDate: today,
        maxDate: function () {
           return $('#endDate').val();
        }
     });
     $('#endDate').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'materialdesign',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        allowInputToggle: true,
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        minDate: function () {
           return $('#startDate').val();
        }
     });
  });
```

The problem: If i choose the area, disabledate show only blank array. Array push process on combobox process is worked (using console.log). **How to pass the array of disdate from combo box function to loaddatepicker function?**

Thank you.

Comment: call loadDatePicker() from your ajax success, configured with the ajax-returned data

Comment: could you explain to me?